# Prove: Use the triangle inequality to prove that for all $x, y, z, | x − z | ≤ | x − y | + | y − z |$

Tags: absolute-value

Prove: Use the triangle inequality to prove that for all $x, y, z, |x-z|≤|x−y|+|y−z|$

Is my proof correct?

> Proof:
>
> Let $a = x-y$, and $b=y-z$.
>
> We can say that $|a+b| = |(x-y) + (y-z)| = |x - z|$.
>
> Further more we can say:
>
> $$|a| + |b -a| \ge |a + b -a| = |b|$$
>
> $$|b| + |a -b| \ge |b + a -b| = |a|$$
>
> Move |a| to the right side in the first inequality and |b| to the second inequality. We get:
>
> $$|b +a| \ge |b| + |a|$$
>
> $$|a +b| \ge |a| +|b|$$
>
> From absolute value properties we know that $|b+a|=|a+b|$
>
> Combining these two facts together we get:
>
> $$|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$$
>
> Which implies
>
> $$|x − z | ≤ | x − y | + | y − z |$$

***Or applying the triangle inequality directly we can also prove it this way:***

> Proof:
>
> Let $a = x-y$, and $b=y-z$.
>
> We can say that $|a+b| = |(x-y) + (y-z)| = |x - z|$.
>
> Substituting $a$ and $b$ into given inequality we get
>
> $$|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$$
>
> which by claim is equivalent to the triangle inequality. QED.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use the triangle inequality". You know already that

$$|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$$

Just set $a = x - y$, $b = y -z$

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

$$|x-z|=|(x-y)+(y-z)|\le |x-y|+|y-z|$$

Comment: I have updated my answer, am I closer?

Comment: @lucidgold, why don't you use *directly* the triangle inequality $\;|a\pm b|\le |a|+|b|\;$ , with $\;a=x-y\;,\;\;b=y-z\;$ ??

Comment: I am not sure how I can just throw it in there. I thought I was breaking it down.. am I re-inventing the wheel? Otherwise am totally lost then.

Comment: @lucidgold, can you assume or prove that $\;|a-b|\le |a|+|b|\;$ ? Because if you can this is **all** we need by the substitution mentioned above! No cases and no nothing else.

Comment: I think you are right, I can do that. I have updated my answer!

Comment: Exactly that, @lucidgold. Good.

Answer (score 0):

hint:set $a=x-y, b=y-z$ and apply traingle inequalitu for $a,b$.